# Ubuntu 16.04, Docker and zero space on volume "Filesystem root"

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage, docker

Earlier today I installed Docker and followed a few tutorials. When running a tutorial on using Docker with a barebones Meteor app, I got an error that there was not enough disk space, even though my `/home` partition has 17 GB free.

I restarted my computer and it informed me that `The volume "Filesystem root" has 0 bytes disk space remaining`. None of my browsers wanted to launch in such a suffocating space.

I ran `sudo apt-get remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io` and this reclaimed 33.4 MB of disk space on `/`, which meant I could launch a browser and look for hints on how to reclaim more space. After removing an old kernel, running `sudo apt autoremove --purge` and `sudo apt-get clean` and removing a number of third-party apps that I haven't used for a while, I have been able to claim back a total of just over 800 MB, so at least I have some breathing space.

However, it seems a coincidence that the installation of Docker and the creation of half a dozen images led to my 19 GB `/` partition suddenly becoming saturated. It also seems that there must still be a lot of space that has not been released, forcing me to remove other files which previously caused no bother.

Is there something special that Docker does to `/`, and is there something I can do to I undo it, and avoid having it happen again?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           783M  9,6M  773M   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   19G   17G  776M  96% /
tmpfs           3,9G  468K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
...
/dev/nvme0n1p6  465M   80M  357M  19% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p7   77G   57G   17G  78% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  496M   82M  415M  17% /boot/efi
tmpfs           783M   52K  783M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that:

- Docker stores its images and containers at `/var/lib/docker/`
- To contain a Meteor app requires 3 images of 907 MB apiece

```
$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              33b3559a88ad        2 minutes ago       907MB
<none>              <none>              f2136da9e497        2 minutes ago       907MB
node                12.6                7c412a558705        12 months ago       907MB
```

That (along with my other experiments) quickly filled my 19 GB partition.

To solve the issue, I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743270/1927589), to create a symbolic link from `/var/lib/docker/` to a folder on the wider plains of my `/home` partition. And my `/` partition thanks me for it:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           783M  9,7M  773M   2% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   19G   15G  3,3G  82% /
...
```

I also used `docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)` and `docker image prune` to remove the huge files that I created while experimenting, which were no longer needed.